# object of type 'closure' is not subsettable error when mapping a function through a split data frame

Tags: r, shiny, split, mapping, reactive

I'm having an issue with my Shiny app where I'm getting the "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable error". I understand that reactive variables are functions so you need to include parenthesis when calling them (df vs df()). However, I suspect this error is coming from a bit of my code where I am mapping a function through a split data frame and then reformatting the results into a data frame using bind_rows.
A sample of my code is below. I suspect the error is occurring at "calc_HIT".

Any help solving this issue would be great!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dataRetrieval)
library(EflowStats)

ui <- fluidPage(
tabPanel("Densities and Hydrologic Indices", fluid = TRUE,
         sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
                 
                 selectInput("USGS", 
                             label = "USGS Gage",
                             choices = list("Above Early Intake"= "11276600", 
                                            "Below Hetch Hetchy" = "11276500", 
                                            "Above Hetch Hetchy" = "11274790"),
                             selected = "11276500"),

                 selectInput("HIT",
                             label = "Hydrologic Index",
                             choices = list("Day minimum flow occurred" = "tl1",
                                            "Day maximum flow occurred" = "th1",
                                            "7-day average max flow" = "dh3",
                                            "7-day average min flow" = "dl3",
                                            "Average duration of high flow event"= "dh20",
                                            "Average duration of low flow event" = "dl16",
                                            "Number of high flow events" = "fh7",
                                            "March high flow event" = "mh3"),
                             selected = "dh3")
             ),

             mainPanel(
                 plotOutput("HITplot"))
         )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {   
 dailyMeanQ <- reactive({
     readNWISdv(siteNumber =input$USGS,
                parameterCd = "00060",
                startDate = ifelse(input$USGS == "11274790",  "2007-10-01", "2006-10-01"),
                endDate = "2019-09-30")
 })
 
 dailyMeanQ_Clean <- reactive({
     validate_data(dailyMeanQ()[c("Date","X_00060_00003")],
                   yearType="water")
 })
 
 siteInfo <- reactive({
     readNWISsite(siteNumber = input$USGS)
 })
 
 drainageArea <- reactive({
     siteInfo()$drain_area_va
 })

 peakFlows <- reactive({
     readNWISpeak(siteNumber = input$USGS,
                           startDate = ifelse(input$USGS == "11274790",  "2007-10-01", "2006-10-01"),
                           endDate = "2020-09-30") 
 })
     
 floodThresh <- reactive({
     get_peakThreshold(dailyMeanQ_Clean()[c("date","discharge")],
                                  peakFlows[c("peak_dt","peak_va")])
 })
 
 calc_HIT<-reactive({
     dailyMeanQ_Clean()%>%
     split(.$year_val)%>%
     lapply(.,function(x){calc_allHIT(x,
                                      drainArea=drainageArea(),
                                      floodThreshold=floodThresh(),
                                      pref="median")})%>%
     bind_rows(.id = "year_val")%>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = "indice", values_from = "statistic")
 })
 

output$HITplot<-renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(calc_HIT(), aes(year_val, input$HIT)) +
           geom_point(aes()) 
}) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use text variables with column names directly in `aes()`. Either use `aes_string()`:

```r
ggplot(calc_HIT(), aes_string("year_val", input$HIT)) +
       geom_point()
```

or better (since `aes_string()` is soft-deprecated):

```r
ggplot(calc_HIT(), aes(year_val, .data[[ input$HIT ]])) +
       geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestions and I'm still getting the same error. I don't think the issue in in the plotting code since the same code works elsewhere in my original script. I'm pretty confident my issue lies in the calc_HIT code.